# acumatica project customizations project ID missing on localhost instance

Tags: acumatica

I have a local instance of Acumatica 2018 R2 that I am using for development and when I try to edit a Customization Project it is not pulling in the specific project and ID.

[Local instance of the Custom Project editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9It7.png)

Where it says "Project" in the top left, it should say "Test5".

Here is how the editor should look:
[Production Instance Custom Project Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKjom.png)

I believe that I've configured my IIS setting correctly but I can't get it to perform correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that happen before. It appears to be an Ajax glitch. When the customization project editor opens it displays `Project` as a placeholder first. Then an Ajax call fetch the proper project name to replace the template placeholder text.

There isn't much to do to resolve this issue. I suggest using a different web browser (Chrome seems to handle Ajax more reliably) and possibly issuing an IISReset command on the web server or if you don't have access to server a restart application from the apply updates page.